# How to fetch Total count of valid email addresses by excluding demo domain like demo.com in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to find out the total number of proper email ids excluding some emails id which have say "demo.com" domains.

I know how to fetch domains from table but didn't find any solution for getting total valid email ids excluding demo email ids like name@demo.com.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT distinct substring_index(`email_id`, '@', -1) as domains, COUNT(*)
FROM user_login
GROUP BY substring_index(`email_id`, '@', -1);
```

Comment: What is an email id?

Comment: it may contain name@gmail.com,name@yahoo.com and name@demo.com. ...... i want to find count of proper email ids excluding "demo.com" patterns.

Comment: What is a "proper email id"?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to filter those rows out?

```
SELECT distinct substring_index(`email_id`, '@', -1) as domains, COUNT(*)
FROM user_login
WHERE `email_id` NOT LIKE '%@demo.com'
GROUP BY substring_index(`email_id`, '@', -1);
```